# django localtime

Tags: django, django-timezone

I'm trying to convert utc times to localtime in my template and for some reason doing:

```
{% load tz %}

{% localtime on %}
{{ value }}
{% endlocaltime %}
```

still gives me the value in utc

however

```
{{ value|localtime }}
```

gives me the value using my local timezone setting

setting USE_TZ in settings.py to True also seems to do nothing

any idea what i'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

The `{{ value }}` date/time object that you are trying to show is a naive datetime object. Naive datetime objects will not convert in template tags - your first example, but will convert in template filters - your 2nd example.

[See the first warning here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/topics/i18n/timezones/#time-zone-aware-output-in-templates)

"Naive" has to do with how the datetime object is created. For info on how to change the date/time object time aware - allowing it to be used in template tags - check out [This Thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10667743/how-to-store-a-naive-datetime-in-django-1-4)

Answer (score 0):

I've created a simple middleware to handle all of this stuff for you:

https://github.com/Miserlou/django-easy-timezones

Simply install it and follow the instructions and you're done!

1. Install django-easy-timezones

   `pip install django-easy-timezones pytz pygeoip`
2. Add "easy-timezones" to your INSTALLED_APPS setting like this:

   `INSTALLED_APPS = (
     ...
     'easy-timezones',
   )`
3. Add EasyTimezoneMiddleware to your MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES

   `MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
     ...
     'easy-timezones.middleware.EasyTimezoneMiddleware',
   )`
4. Add a path to the [MaxMind GeoIP database](http://www.maxmind.com/en/geolocation_landing) in your settings file:

   `GEOIP_DATABASE = '/path/to/your/geoip/database/GeoIP.dat'`
5. Enable localtime in your templates.

   `{% load tz %}
       The UTC time is {{ object.date }}
   {% localtime on %}
       The local time is {{ object.date }}
   {% endlocaltime %}`
6. Tada!